# Fear of electric arcs on a multiple outlet

Tags: design, physical-design, arc, outlet

I am physically near a multiple power outlet of the following model:

[image]

The official page of the article is [PowerCube |Extended|](http://www.allocacoc.com/Product/detail/id/1199/product_group_id/44.html)

My doubt is: each outlet seems to close to each other. Should I fear the creation of electric arcs on such a device? I already had the same doubt for years on simpler triple outlets like:

[image]

[image]

Comment: All the outlet extenders you show are meant for indoor use, where they are expected to remain dry and relatively clean. Used like this, they won't spontaneously arc. They might arc from a nearby lightning strike, but that arc self-extinguishes very quickly. Your worry is unlikely- there are other hazards in your electrical system that have a higher probability of doing you harm.

Comment: If its been certified by an ETL you have no need to worry.

Answer (score 3):

Not under ordinary conditions, no.  The people who designed the standards for these were aware of the relevant science, for example that it takes on the order of 3 million volts per meter to strike an arc in air.  There has also been several career generations worth of time and experience to work expectable variation of conditions, effects of sharp edges, etc into those standards.

If you consider the voltages and geometry, if an arc were going to happen, it wouldn't happen between the distinct outlet receptacles, but rather between the closer and opposite potential parts of a single outlet.  So going by *externally visible* detail alone, these multi outlets wouldn't seem to be more susceptible to arcing than single receptacle ones.

What we can't know from the external pictures however is if the *internal* construction of *these particular* examples is in accordance with all applicable codes, standards, and sound practices - in a bad design, internal parts could be close enough to arc even if external ones aren't.

Answer (score 1):

AC with inductive loads will arc when unplugged. *This is normal.* With capacitive loads there is a small arc when making contact with bounce. *This is normal.* The arc is very small x mm.  Battery Chargers and SMPS have both L and C parts so they have a small arc on both insertion and withdraw.

A large motor is just inductive when current is drawn, a longer the arc is also drawn by x mm. So for those reasons, an external switch is often used, but it is still safe to pull the plug.  But you hold the plug by the insulator and not squeezing the live pins.

Air arcs may occur from 1~3kV/mm to breakdown, but when pulling a plug an arc starts the moment contact is broken 0mm and then is drawn out several mm until extinguished. *This is normal and safe* unless beside flammable liquids soaked on the socket.  Common sense tells you not to do that or play with matches on same liquids.

Answer (score 0):

You are being silly.

The opposite sides of the power don't look any closer to each other in the power cube than they do in the outlet it is plugged into in the first place.  Have you even heard of a normal outlet arcing?  Right.  I didn't think so.

Also, surely you must be aware that there are legal rules, such as something called the *electric code*.  Do you really imagine that outlets would be allowed if they routinely arc?  Do you really think that the people that design, manufacture, and sell these devices don't have any rules to follow, and aren't aware of basic physics like arcing?

*Think* about it a little.

Comment: Sometimes, when I insert a jack into a wall outlet I see an annoying flash. Isn't that an arc?

Comment: @serg: You asked about the Power Cube and similar devices arcing on their own.  There can be small sparks when a cord is plugged in and unplugged to/from a outlet, but that is quite different from what you asked about.